# Does loot qualty vary more for co-op than solo?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

Will levels drop better loot depending on how many you are playing with?

If so, will the loot quality also vary between 2, 3 and 4 player co-op?

Comment: posting as comment since I can't confirm.  I think the level of the players also affect loot quality.  If you join a game with all high levels (60+) you'll find tons of legendary and epic items, but on the same map with only level 35s, you won't see a single one (or very rarely).

Comment: @yx: Are you sure that wasn't due to the difficulty setting?

Comment: @BlueRaja yes, my level 70finds legendaries on hard summit when my level 45 ranked squire doesn't

Comment: @yx So a better question would actually be: "What affects the quality of dropped loot?". Hmm.

Comment: @mordi2k yes, that would be interesting to find out.  Although the 'reward' items from challenges and bosses seems to be completely random, recently found a legendary off of the hard summit boss on a level 40 dude.

Comment: @yx I doubt it would be good fit tho, as it would pretty much be a list and speculation question. So it would probably be filled up with a lot of answer that are all correct in some way.

Comment: @mordi2k: It wouldn't necessarily be speculation - someone could just reverse-engineer the game (or we could just look at the source code, [when it comes out](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33203))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quality of the loot dropped in a map is dependent on these things:

- The map in question
- The difficulty you chose for the map
- What wave it was when the loot dropped

Loot quality does not vary based on players. However, more loot drops during co-op because you are fighting and killing more mobs. Because of the fact that you are killing more mobs and seeing more loot, it will seem as though there is more variety. In actuality, you're seeing the same variety (percentage chance of drop for each quality), but you're seeing more of it.