# Where can I find the source code for Dungeon Defenders?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

[According to the wiki](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Mods), the PC version of Dungeon Defenders comes with the *"gameplay code and source"* for UDK, for the purposes of modding.

However, it's not listed in the usual place (*"Tools"* in Steam), and I can't find any other info online.  Where is the source code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the optional DLC where the source code is located [here](http://store.steampowered.com/app/202522), or you can find it under the DLC tab in the store page.

Now you can find the source code located at `\Steam\steamapps\common\dungeon defenders\Development\Src\`

> \Development\Src: This contains all the gameplay source code for Dungeon Defenders (in UnrealScript, which you can learn through the Unreal Developer Network). It's located here for Mod coding & reference purposes in particular.

[Source](http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?22746-Dungeon-Defenders-Development-Kit-Basic-Overview&p=168610&viewfull=1#post168610)

Comment: awesome, it'll be good to finally see some of the formulas in the game.

Comment: Cool, a small note about how to install it (for googlers) and I will give you the checkmark

Comment: Added now @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it was delayed. For those who don't need the latest and greatest, there's a [link](http://download.udk.com/blog/dungeon_defense_source_final.zip) on the [UDK Page](http://www.udk.com/showcase-dungeon-defense).

Comment: That source is older than dust, and completely useless for modding.

Answer (score -3):

It's under steam's tools section now!

Comment: Er, where?  I don't see it.

Comment: title? link? anything to back this up?

Comment: Not seeing it either. Are you posting this in case it becomes correct at some point, or what?